# My function containing a mysql query launched by ajax is not working in wordpress. What am I missing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to insert rows into a table I've set up based on user's answers. I have made a child theme and a custom template for the page with the form. My issue is that I have no way of knowing what's going wrong where and why the data isn't being inserted. my js onclick function is as follows, and this file is called question_submit.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#questionSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url:  my_ajax_object.ajax_url, 
            data: { 
                'action' : 'dbtest',
                'option': 1, 
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Here is where I enqueue the script:

```
function my_enqueue() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'question_submit', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/question_submit.js', array('jquery') );
      wp_localize_script( 'question_submit', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

And finally here is the function that's binded to the action:

```
function dbtesting(){
    
    global $wpdb;
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    //$option = sanitize_text_field($_POST["option"]);
    
    $tableName = 'user_answers';
    $insert_row = $wpdb->insert( 
                    $tableName, 
                    array( 
                        'user_id' => 2, 
                        'module_id' => 3, 
                        'section_id' => 1, 
                        'question_id' => 2,
                        'option_no' => 1, 
                    )
                );
    // if row inserted in table
    if($insert_row){
        echo json_encode(array('res'=>true, 'message'=>__('New row has been inserted.')));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('res'=>false, 'message'=>__('Something went wrong. Please try again later.')));
    }
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dbtest', 'dbtesting' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dbtest', 'dbtesting' );
```

Both of these functions are in my child theme's functions.php file. Right now I am using hard-coded values jsut to test the functionality, later these values will be dependent on the form answers.

When I click the submit button, there is no change in my table but also no php errors.

Comment: What is the last set of code that executes? Does the alert come up, does the ajax request get sent to the server, does dbtesting() get called, etc?

Comment: the last set of code that executes for sure is the alert('clicked'). How would I go about confirming if dbtesting() gets called?

Comment: You can open your browser's developer tools if you're using Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE or Edge and go to the Network > AJAX/XHR section. Each browser will have different terminology, so you may have to look for similar words. That will tell you if the ajax was sent and what the request and response look like. You can also add a `complete` callback on the ajax, and `console.log` the response. To see what came back, in case it failed. Then you can see why it failed.

Comment: The XHR section is blank so I assume the request is never being sent

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange. Then the only thing it could be is the `my_ajax_object.ajax_url` is not defined on the page. Please check that. Are there any errors in the console prior or during the attempt of the ajax call?

Comment: Also, you may need to move this question into the Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or WordPress https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ Community. I'm pretty sure you just have a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: Also, what does the `complete` ajax callback show?

Comment: @PHilF please don't suggest users post questions involving code that is not working on Code Review since that is not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Comment: How would I check if my_ajax_object.ajax_url is defined or not? There are no errors in the console prior to or during the attempt of the call. Thanks for the advice, I'll move this question into code review and wordpress stackexchange

Comment: When I add complete : function(){ console.log("complete");} I do see complete being printed on the console

Comment: @SAM, sure I wasn't intending to suggest, only point out if there is a bug there *may* be better communities for that and offer some possible options to investigate to see if they may be a good fit or not. I can try and be clearer next time.

Comment: @kenyac please see SAM's comment. Code Review would NOT be a good fit for this. I was only mentioning it as a possibility, but that community has said it off-topic.

Comment: @PhilF Thank you, I have posted a copy with some edits in the wordpress stack exchange but I won't be posting it to code review.